# how to send bulk sms to mobile numbers in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I send a message to more than 50 mobiles at a time? The code below will execute but it takes a long time.

```
<?php
    $sqljobseekers=$con->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $y=mysqli_num_rows($sqljobseekers);

    while($jobseekers=$sqljobseekers->fetch_assoc()) {
       $seekermobile=$jobseekers['emp_mobile'];
       $msg="Dear Candidate, .".$job_cmp_name.". is looking .".$jobrolename.". like u, for more details logon www.venkymama.com / www.lifemadeeasyglobal.com";
       $msg=urlencode($msg);
       $sms_file="http://tra.bulksmshyderabad.co.in/websms/sendsms.aspx?userid=$user&password=$password&sender=atmm&mobileno=".$seekermobile."&msg=$msg.";    
       $sms_h=fopen($sms_file,"r");
       fclose($sms_h);
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Most likely the slow part is the communication with that API, nothing php can do about that. Your option obviously is to switch to an asynchronous approach and use a job scheduler.

Comment: did you find where is the issue?If your mysql query took long time for billion data, then optimize your query. If SMS provider is slow, then contact with them.Also youcan't send billion SMS at a time, SO will suggest you to add limit in your query.

Comment: also check if provider has any option/api to send bulk sms.

Comment: looks like a rather insecure way of sending data

Comment: Everytime a programmer writes Select * a kitten dies.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through your users, making an API call, waiting for a response, and moving onto the next user; why not execute all the calls at the same time?

Take a look into [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). It will allow you to send multiple API calls at the same time. Something similar to this:

```
<?php
    $sqljobseekers=$con->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $y=mysqli_num_rows($sqljobseekers);

    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    while($jobseekers=$sqljobseekers->fetch_assoc()) {
       $seekermobile=$jobseekers['emp_mobile'];
       $msg="Dear Candidate, .".$job_cmp_name.". is looking .".$jobrolename.". like u, for more details logon www.venkymama.com / www.lifemadeeasyglobal.com";
       $msg=urlencode($msg);
       $sms_file="http://tra.bulksmshyderabad.co.in/websms/sendsms.aspx?userid=$user&password=$password&sender=atmm&mobileno=".$seekermobile."&msg=$msg.";    
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sms_file);
       curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    }

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}
}

?>
```